# Object detection in 2D laser scan

Tags: opencv, registration, point-cloud-library, ros, object-detection

Currently, I desperately try to detect an object (robot) based on 2D laser scans (of another robot). In the following two pictures, the blue arrow corresponds to the pose of the laser scanner and points towards the object, that I would like to detect.

[one side of the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKzpJ.png)

[two sides of the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oUjK.png)

Since it is basically a 2D picture, my first approach was to to look for some OpenCV implementations such as `HoughLinesP` or `LSDDetector` in order to detect the lines. Unfortunately, since the focus of OpenCV is more on "real" images with "real" lines, this approach does not really work with the point clouds, as far as I have understood it correctly. Another famous library is the point-cloud library, which on the other hand focus more on 3D point clouds.

My current approach would be to segment the laser scans and then use some iterative closest point (ICP) C++ implementation to find a 2D point cloud template in the laser scans. Since I am not that familiar with object detection and all that nice stuff, I am quite sure that there are some more sophisticated solutions...

Do you have any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

To get lines from points, you could try [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).
You would iteratively fit lines to the points, then remove points corresponding to the new line and repeat until there is not enough points or the support is too low or something like that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the problem is that lines are a really rough approximation of the robot's shape. Furthermore, I think that an adjusted RANSAC takes quite some time to compute, since I have to fit a new line for every new point.

Comment: Well, it is hard to infer the shape of the robot from your question. But you can fit any shape with RANSAC, you just need to provide the function, which determines if a subset of points fits the model well.